# getCurrentPosition is not working in Android Phone and emulator

Tags: eclipse, html, cordova

I want to know current geolacation of user in HTML5 app (Eclipse using PhoneGap). i am using geolocation.getCurrentPosition function.But it is not working in android phone and emulator.

This line is using in html page ready function :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,{maximumAge:600000, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
```

But always showing error with error **code**:3 and **message**:Timeout expired

Comment: If the timeout is expiring, consider increasing the timeout.  Five seconds isn't really a lot of time to get a GPS lock.  Also, have you confirmed the GPS is enabled on your device?

Comment: I increased timeout form 5000 to 30000. but still showing error and going in else part. why :(